# problem with Context "getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference"

Tags: java, android

I made nonActivity class, and I use there other nonActivity Database class. When I call method from 1st class I have Error

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference`

Here is a fragment of my code of both classes:

DataBase.java

```
 public DataBase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, TABLE_VERSION);
   }
```

and ObliczPodatki.java

```
public class ObliczPodatki extends Application
.
.
.
myDb = new DataBase(this.getApplicationContext());
```

and the full error message:

```
Process: com.example.nadgraniav01, PID: 11274
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:116)
        at com.example.nadgraniav01.ObliczPodatki.obliczPodatki(ObliczPodatki.java:43)
        at com.example.nadgraniav01.DodajNadgranieActivity$2.onClick(DodajNadgranieActivity.java:99)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6669)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6638)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:789)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26145)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

if I use this instead of this.getApplicationContext() I am getting following erroe

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: what if you use `this` instead of `this.getApplicationContext()` ?

Comment: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference` - the same error

Comment: Guess: you're trying to instantiate an activity yourself with `new ObliczPodatki()` - that won't work

Comment: @laalto I do it in Activity

Comment: I did in MainActivity in onCreate section `ObliczPodatki obliczPodatki = new ObliczPodatki();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this then:

```
 @Override 
 public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate() 
  SQLiteHandler db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());
  ....rest of db calls..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 myDb = new DataBase(getApplicationContext());
```

Or,

```
 myDb = new DataBase(Activityname.this);
```

Answer (score 0):

`getApplicationContext` is not the context that you should use,

Use this instead

```
myDb = new DataBase(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialise `myDb` variable in `onCreate()` method of `ObliczPodatki` class.

```
   myDb = new DataBase(getApplicationContext());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the DB object in onCreate() Of Application.
please follow below example

```
    public class ObliczPodatki extends Application {
            // Called when the application is starting, before any other application objects have been created.
            // Overriding this method is totally optional!
        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
                // Required initialization logic here!

                myDb = new DataBase(getApplicationContext());
        }
    
            // Called by the system when the device configuration changes while your component is running.
            // Overriding this method is totally optional!
        @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        }
    
            // This is called when the overall system is running low on memory, 
            // and would like actively running processes to tighten their belts.
            // Overriding this method is totally optional!
        @Override
        public void onLowMemory() {
            super.onLowMemory();
        }
    }
```

And specify the android:name property in the the  node in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application 
   android:name=". ObliczPodatki"
   android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
   android:label="@string/app_name" 
   ...>
```